# Перебор свойств объекта и вывод в таблицу

Tags: javascript, массивы, json, объекты, таблицы

Прошу помощи. 
Как создать таблицу и заполнить значениями,а столбец address вывести city + street (т.е. город и улица в одной строке)?
Есть некий json файл в котором данные подобного вида:

```
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Smith",
    "address": {
      "city": "Tashkent",
      "street": "Lenina Street 3"
    }
]
```

Я делал следующим образом

```
<body>
<div id="table-list"></div>
<script>

fetch('someURL.json')
.then(function (response) {
return response.json()
})
.then(function (data) { 
createTable(data);
})

function createTable(array) {

        var testOne = array.length;

        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.setAttribute('border', '1');
        table.setAttribute('color', '000');
        table.setAttribute('width','500');
        table.setAttribute('height', '300');

        var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tr.innerHTML = '<td>id</td><td>Name</td><td>Adress</td>';
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
        var items = ['id','name','address'],address = 'city';

        for(var i = 0; i < testOne; i++){
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    var td = document.createElement('td');
                    var item = array[i][items[j]];
                    //td.innerHTML =  item;
                    td.innerHTML = item[address] ? item[address] : item;
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                }
                tbody.appendChild(tr);
        }
        table.appendChild(tbody);
        document.getElementById('table-list').appendChild(table);
}
</script>
</body>
```

Однако данный подход кажется мне не правильным.

Правильней будет осуществить перебор свойств объекта в цикле и этом же цикле сделать создание таблицы.

*Прошу прощения за кровь из глаз.Я лишь учусь.*

Сначала мне казалось  - сделаю хоть как нибудь, но сегодня прочитав пару тройку статей по объектам понял, что подход не верен.

```
(testOne[i].address.city + '' + testOne[i].address.street)
```

пробовал присваивать переменной данное выражение - не помогало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там, где заранее не известно точное количество элементов можно воспользоваться конструкцией `for (property in Object)` ([Подробнее](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-for-in)).

Например, для случая выше:

```js
var json = [
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "John",
    "address": {
      "city": "Tashkent",
      "street": "Lenina Street 3"
    }},
    {
    "id": "124",
    "name": "Smith",
    "address": {
      "city": "Moscow",
      "street": "Arbat str. 5"
    }
  }
];

var tableContent = '<table>';
tableContent += '<tr><td>Name</td><td>Address</td></tr>';

for (p in json){
  tableContent += '<tr><td>' + json[p].name + '</td>';
  tableContent += '<td>' + json[p].address.city + " " + json[p].address.street + '</td></tr>';
}
tableContent += '</table>';

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = tableContent;
```

```css
table { 
  border: 1px solid #000; 
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 2px;
}
tr:nth-child(1) {
  background: #cce6ff;
}
```

Формирование таблицы намеренно пропущу, т.к. в каждом конкретном случае это происходит по разному и решения тоже разные.

> Я лишь учусь.

Всё хорошо. Все учимся. Главное - не сдавайтесь.

**UPD:** Пример с выводом всё же обновил, но это только как пример, а не рекомендация по использованию.

Comment: Размер известен. Подобная конструкция сегодня встречалась, пробовал не получилось. Ну с созданием и  заполнением таблицы постараюсь разобраться. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Ошибки бывают разные. Пробуйте отлаживать, выводить, что содержит та или иная переменная. Возможно, сам JSON был не валидным, его тоже надо проверять на валидность.

Comment: Вроде получается, только вот не могу понять как вывести все объекты json через цикл  и задать правило вывода address.

Comment: Доступ к полям JSON объекта осуществляется через точку. Попробуйте для начала выполнить код `for (p in json){
  console.log(json[p]);
}` и посмотреть, что он выведет в консоли.

Comment: Выводит все значения.

Comment: Хорошо. Пробуйте дальше в цикле через точку получать доступ к нужным полям. Например, `json[p].address.city` и т. д.

Comment: for (i in array){ console.log(array[i].address.city + " " + array[i].address.street); } Тоже работает и выводит как положено. К любому объекту обращение выполняется.

Comment: Ну да. Только вот как теперь церез цикл правильно  присвоить значения элементам таблицы и тот самый адрес в формате город + улица. По сути таблица создается через цикл. Вроде бы все нормально но вот с выводом в таблицу  -беда.

Comment: Обновил код для примера.

Comment: Только 1 вопрос не будет ли проблем когда дело дойдет до сортировки таблицы? Просто далее потребуется сортировка таблицы но в данной теме о ней говорить думаю не будет приемлемо, т.к. основной вопрос решён.

Comment: Сортировка в таблице - это уже другой вопрос, выходящий за рамки этой темы. А так - опять же, смотря как реализовать сортировку. В примере выше можно отсортировать без проблем.