# Javascript фильтр таблиц

Tags: javascript, html, table, фильтрация

В таблице есть столбец с адресами формата: **"город" + "улица и дом"**.
Значения в таблицу попадают из json файла. С перебором свойств объекта и добавлением адреса мне помогли [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/986280/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83)

Однако снова возникла проблема с этим же столбцом.
Вопрос- как мне вывести по фильтру **город** список адресов в формате **"город" + "улица и дом"**

Для примера - в таблице есть города без адреса они выводятся, но города с адресом не будет выводится т.к. в

```
<option value="Moscow">Moscow</option>
```

Указан только город. 
Как сделать фильтр таблицы без учета полного значения строки?  Чтобы при выборе Москва выводились все значения где есть Москва.

*Прошу прощения за кровь из глаз.Я лишь учусь.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TABLE FILTER</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Helvetica";
      font-size: medium;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    table td,
    table th {
      border: solid 1px #aaa;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    table tbody tr:nth-child(2n) {
      background: #a8d7ff;
    }
    
    table tbody tr:hover {
      background: #fffcb6;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Фильтр данных в таблицах.</h1>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Символы</th>
        <th>Текст</th>
        <th>Город</th>
        <th>Цифры</th>
        <th>Текст</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="charA" value="A" />A
          <input type="checkbox" id="charB" value="B" />B
          <input type="checkbox" id="charC" value="C" />C
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <select id="digits">
            <option value="">---</option>
            <option value="Москва">Москва</option>
            <option value="Ташкент">Ташкент</option>
            <option value="СПб">СПб</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="digit" id="radioZ" value="" checked="true" />-
          <input type="radio" name="digit" id="radioA" value="1" />1
          <input type="radio" name="digit" id="radioB" value="2" />2
          <input type="radio" name="digit" id="radioC" value="3" />3
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="regexp" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="target">
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>Арбуз</td>
        <td>Москва</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Фанат</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>Стрелок</td>
        <td>Москва</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Арба</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>Фанат</td>
        <td>СПб Ленина 12</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Стрелок</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>Стрелок</td>
        <td>Ташкент Бабура 21</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Фантомас</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>Стрелок</td>
        <td>Москва Жукова 1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Арбуз</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>Фанат</td>
        <td>Ташкент</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Стрелок</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Арбуз</td>
        <td>СПб</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Арбуз</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Фанат</td>
        <td>Ташкент</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Стрелочник</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>Фанат</td>
        <td>СПб Королёва 122</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Арбуз</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>Фанат</td>
        <td>Ташкент Ленина 111</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Фантик</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>Стрелок</td>
        <td>Ташкент</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Арбуз</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>Фанат</td>
        <td>Москва</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Стрелка</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script> /**
 * Created by Komarov Artem on 11.08.14.
 */

/**
 * Привязать фильтры к таблице.
 * @param HTMLTableSectionElement HTMLTBodyRef - ссылка на элемент &lt;tbody&gt; таблицы
 * @param Object filters - объект-конфигурация фильтров: { N : FILTER[, N : FILTER] }
 *
 *  Где:
 *      NUM - это натуральное число - номер столбца таблицы, обслуживаемого
 *          фильтром. Этот номер может принимать значения от 0 до кол-во
 *          столбцов таблицы - 1. Номера можно задавать не по порядку.
 *
 *      FILTER - это ссылка на HTML-элемент представляющий собой элемент
 *          HTML-формы и имеющий атрибут value (select в том числе), либо
 *          объект типа tableKit.Filter
 */
var filterTable = function (HTMLTBodyRef, aFilters) {
    var rows = HTMLTBodyRef.getElementsByTagName("TR"),
        filters = {}, n,
        walkThrough = function (rows) {
            var tr, i, f;
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i += 1) {
                tr = rows.item(i);
                for(f in filters) {
                    if (filters.hasOwnProperty(f)) {
                        if (false === filters[f].validate(tr.children[f].innerText) ) {
                            tr.style.display = "none"; break;
                        } else {
                            tr.style.display = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    for(n in aFilters) {
        if (aFilters.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
            if (aFilters[n] instanceof filterTable.Filter) {
                filters[n] = aFilters[n];
            } else {
                filters[n] = new filterTable.Filter(aFilters[n]);
            }
            filters[n]._setAction("onchange", function () {walkThrough(rows);});
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Объект фильтр.
 * @param HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelect HTMLElementRef | [] - Ссылка или массив ссылок
 *                 на html-элементы, служащие фильтрами.
 * @param Function callback - ф-ция обратного вызова. Вызывается когда скрипт
 * производит валидацию содержимого ячейки. Ф-ция вызывается для каждой строки таблицы, для
 * каждой ячейки столбца, для которого назначен фильтр.
 * Функции будут переданы 3 параметра: callback(value, filters, i) где:
 *      String value - значение ячейки таблицы, проверяемой на момент вызова ф-ции
 *      HTMLElements[] filters - массив HTML-элементов назначенных фильтрами для проверяемого столбца.
 *      Number i - индекс элемента фильтра в массиве filters который является
 *                 валидатором для текущего вызова. Т.е. filters[i] внутри ф-ции
 *                 обратного вызова будет содержать элемент, с которым провзаимодействовал
 *                 пользователь, в результате чего был запущен процесс валидации.
 * @param String eventName - название события привязанного к фильтру, по которому будет
 *      запускаться валидация (onkeyup | onclick | onblur | onchange и т.п.)
 * @constructor
 */
filterTable.Filter = function (HTMLElementRef, callback, eventName) {
    /* Если ф-цию вызвали не как конструктор фиксим этот момент: */
    if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
        return new arguments.callee(HTMLElementRef, callback, eventName);
    }

    /* Выравниваем пришедший аргумент к массиву */
    this.filters = {}.toString.call(HTMLElementRef) == "[object Array]" ? HTMLElementRef : [HTMLElementRef];

    /**
     * Шаблонный метод вызывается для каждой строки таблицы, для соответствующей
     * ячейки. Номер ячейки задается в объекте-конфигурации фильтров ф-ции
     * filterTable (См. параметр 2 ф-ции tableFilter )
     * @param String cellValue - строковое значение ячейки
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    this.validate = function (cellValue) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.filters.length; i += 1) {
            if ( false === this.__validate(cellValue, this.filters[i], i) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    this.__validate = function (cellValue, filter, i) {
        /* Если фильтр был создан явно и явно указана функция валидации: */
        if (typeof callback !== "undefined") {
            return callback(cellValue, this.filters, i);
        }
        /* Если в фильтр напихали пробелов или другой непечатной фигни - удаляем: */
        filter.value = filter.value.replace(/^\s+$/g, "");
        /* "Фильтр содержит значение и оно совпало со значением ячейки" */
        return !filter.value || filter.value == cellValue;
    }

    this._setAction = function (anEventName, callback) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.filters.length; i += 1) {
            this.filters[i][eventName||anEventName] = callback;
        }
    }
};
</script>
  <script>
    filterTable(document.getElementById("target"), {
      /* Фильтр для первого столбца чекбоксы: */
      0: new filterTable.Filter([ /* Элементы фильтра */
          document.getElementById("charA"),
          document.getElementById("charB"),
          document.getElementById("charC")
        ],
        /* Коллбэк ф-ция валидации */
        function(value, filters, i) {
          /* Если чекбокс не отмечен - его значение не учавствует
             в валидации поэтому мы обязаны вернуть true */
          if (false === filters[i].checked) return true;
          /* Далее, при проверке, мы должны одновременно проверять
             значения всех элементов набора при условии чекбокс
             отмечен */
          return filters[0].checked && filters[0].value === value ||
            filters[1].checked && filters[1].value === value ||
            filters[2].checked && filters[2].value === value;
        }
      ),

      /* Фильтр для второго столбца текстовое поле - только точное совпадение: */
      1: document.getElementById("text"),

      /* Фильтр для третьего столбца выпадающий список: */
      2: document.getElementById("digits"),

      /* Фильтр для четвертого столбца радио кнопки: */
      3: new filterTable.Filter([ /* Элеменеты фильтра */
          document.getElementById("radioZ"),
          document.getElementById("radioA"),
          document.getElementById("radioB"),
          document.getElementById("radioC")
        ],
        /* Коллбэк ф-ция валидации */
        function(value, filters, i) {
          /* В filters[0] - у нас радио кнопка "Не выбрано", если она
             установлена фильтр не участвует в валидации и мы
             обязаны вернуть true */
          if (true === filters[0].checked) return true;
          /* Если какая то радиокнопка отмечена и содержимое проверяемой
            ячейки совпало то вернем true */
          return filters[1].checked && filters[1].value === value ||
            filters[2].checked && filters[2].value === value ||
            filters[3].checked && filters[3].value === value;
        }
      ),

      /* Фильтр для пятого столбца Постепенный ввод слова: */
      4: new filterTable.Filter(document.getElementById("regexp"),
        /* Коллбэк ф-ция валидации */
        function(value, filters, i) {
          return value.indexOf(filters[i].value) === 0;
        },
        /* Будем вызывать валидацию по событию onkeyup фильтра */
        "onkeyup"
      )
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А в вашем json город отдельно хранится? В любом случае, для уменьшения работы с DOM лучше фильтровать в json, а в таблицу выводить уже отфильтрованное

Answer (score 0):

Кажется нашёл решение

```
str.match(reg) с флагом g
```